# Call api using HttpClientFactory in Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

I've created an API with CRUD operations. Everything works fine in postman, But when I try to call Patch Method using HttpClientFactory, I get an error(MethodNotAllowed). I have a table with bootstrap icon for edit. When you click on that icon, You are directed to the view of user with the id passed in asp-route-id. When you fill the form with post method, You should see the updated user with same Id. I defined two actions for GET And POST. In Get you get the user with id and in POST you post the user object using HttpMethod.Patch. Patch method in API Controller has two parameters(int id, Player player)

Here is the API controller action

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Player>> UpdatePlayer(Player player, int id)
        {

            if (player == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            if (player.Id != id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
                await _playerRepository.UpdatePlayer(player);
            return Ok(player);
        }
```

Here is two methods for calling API and return a View

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdatePlayer(int id)
        {
            Player player = new Player();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:42045/api/player/" + id);
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            if(response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var apiString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                player = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Player>(apiString);
            }
            return View(player);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdatePlayer(Player player)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Patch, "http://localhost:42045/api/player/");
            if(player != null)
            {
                request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(player),
                    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            }
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            if(response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                ViewBag.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
                var apiString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                player = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Player>(apiString);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
            }
            return View(player);
        }
```

And this is the View

```
@model Player
@{ 
    ViewData["title"] = "Update Player";
}
@if(ViewBag.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                <h2 class="text-center text-success">@ViewBag.StatusCode</h2>
            }
            else
            {
                <h2 class="text-center text-danger">@ViewBag.StatusCode</h2>
            }
<h2>Update Player</h2>
<form class="mt-3" method="post">
    <label asp-for="Name"></label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <label asp-for="Position"></label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input asp-for="Position" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <label asp-for="Nationality"></label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input asp-for="Nationality" class="form-control" />
    </div> <br />
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Update Player</button>

</form>

@if (Model != null)
{
                <table class="table text-center table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Position</th>
                            <th>Nationality</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Model.Id</td>
                            <td>@Model.Name</td>
                            <td>@Model.Position</td>
                            <td>@Model.Nationality</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            }
```

Comment: For starters, the player id is missing from the patch request's URI.

Answer (score 0):

**MethodNotAllowed**

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 405 Method Not Allowed response status code indicates that the server knows the request method, but the target resource doesn't support this method.

So in your code, why you use get and patch like below ?

```
//Get
HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:42045/api/player/" + id
//PATCH
HttpMethod.Patch, "http://localhost:42045/api/player/"
```

You have confused some interfaces by using it this way.

#### Suggestions

1. Please use postman to test every function in your controller.
2. If it still not works for you, please set breakpoint in your method when using `HttpClientFactory` to invoke the patch method.